# Iterative pairwise comparisons across columns in R

Tags: r, algorithm, performance, linear-regression

I have a very large matrix 200 x 1500, where the rows are samples and the columns are data. I want to do pairwise comparisons of all 1500 columns (~1.1M tests), so `combn` would take too long. I'm trying to run a linear model on the first column against each 1499 other columns, process/write the pvalue to output file (i.e.data1.tsv) and then repeat for the second column (excluding the comparison with the first column) and save to data2.tsv. And continue until all comparisons have been made. Below is the code for what I am trying to achieve.

```
library(data.table)

df = as.data.frame(matrix(runif(20, min=0, max=100), nrow=4))
colnames(df) = c("data_1", "data_2", "data_3", "data_4", "data_5")
rownames(df) = c("sample_1", "sample_2", "sample_3", "sample_4")

pval_1 = as.numeric(summary(lm(data_1 ~ data_2, data=df))$coefficients[,"Pr(>|t|)"][2])
pval_2 = as.numeric(summary(lm(data_1 ~ data_3, data=df))$coefficients[,"Pr(>|t|)"][2])
pval_3 = as.numeric(summary(lm(data_1 ~ data_4, data=df))$coefficients[,"Pr(>|t|)"][2])
pval_4 = as.numeric(summary(lm(data_1 ~ data_5, data=df))$coefficients[,"Pr(>|t|)"][2])

data_1 = data.frame(id1 = c("data_1","data_1","data_1","data_1"),
                     id2 = c("data_2","data_3","data_4","data_5"),
                      pval = c(pval_1, pval_2,pval_3,pval_4))

fwrite(data_1, to_path)

pval_5 = as.numeric(summary(lm(data_2 ~ data_3, data=df))$coefficients[,"Pr(>|t|)"][2])
pval_6 = as.numeric(summary(lm(data_2 ~ data_4, data=df))$coefficients[,"Pr(>|t|)"][2])
pval_7 = as.numeric(summary(lm(data_2 ~ data_5, data=df))$coefficients[,"Pr(>|t|)"][2])

data_2 = data.frame(id1 = c("data_2","data_2","data_2"),
                     id2 = c("data_3","data_4","data_5"),
                      pval = c(pval_5, pval_6,pval_7))

fwrite(data_2, to_path)

pval_8 = as.numeric(summary(lm(data_3 ~ data_4, data=df))$coefficients[,"Pr(>|t|)"][2])
pval_9 = as.numeric(summary(lm(data_3 ~ data_5, data=df))$coefficients[,"Pr(>|t|)"][2])

data_3 = data.frame(id1 = c("data_3","data_3"),
                     id2 = c("data_4","data_5"),
                      pval = c(pval_8,pval_9))

fwrite(data_3, to_path )
```

Comment: Have you already tried with `combn` and it is too slow?

Comment: Yeah, `combn` is fine for this example 1,500 data columns, but I'm doing this for 22 chromosomes and some have 12,000 data columns which leads to 77M pairwise tests. I need to split it up and submit it to a cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why it is important to split the files instead of creating a dataframe containing all the pairwise p-values between variables.

Being said that, take a look.

I created a random dataframe with the dimension that you want to work (by the way, this is not that large...):

```
library(Hmisc)
df = as.data.frame(matrix(runif(200 * 1500,  min=0, max=10), nrow=200))
```

Later, by using the function `rcorr` from the Hmisc library. I runned the correlation matrix that will provide you also the p-values between variables.

```
mycor <- rcorr(as.matrix(df), type="pearson")
mycor_p = mycor$P
```

Having done that, I extract the upper matrix from the `mycor_p` matrix and create a 3-column matrix.

```
index <- which(upper.tri(mycor_p, diag = TRUE), arr.ind = TRUE)
dim_n <- dimnames(mycor_p)
res = data.frame(row = dim_n[[1]][index[, 1]],
           col = dim_n[[2]][index[, 2]],
           val = mycor_p[index])
```

Finally, remove `NA` cases

```
final_df = res[complete.cases(res), ]
```

And export this dataframe:

```
write.csv(final_df, file = your_path, row.names=FALSE)
```